# OS X: where to show tooltips for menu items

Tags: macos, tooltip, menuitem

For Windows applications it is quite common to show verbose descriptions of menu items in the status bar if hovering over them. Where to show similar information in Mac applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Mac apps I've used don't have menu item tool tips.  But if they do, they're near the menu item, and usually not that verbose.  You can provide the tool tip text at design time in the menu nib, or at run time by calling `-[NSMenuItem setToolTip:]`, and the OS determines where to place the tool tip.