# SWT: show tooltips for menu items

Tags: java, swt

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373777/os-x-where-to-show-tooltips-for-menu-items) one has to show tooltips if one wants to add more information to menu items. How to do this with SWT? There seems to be no API, neither in `Menu` not in `MenuItem`.

Comment: If it's possible for you to use [JFace elements](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Using_JFace_outside_the_Eclipse_platform) you can use the [MenuManager](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Faction%2FMenuManager.html) instead of Menu/MenuItem. [Example here](http://hexapixel.com/2009/05/22/menumanagers-and-you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct API to show tooltip  on `Menu` or`MenuItem`. You should be able to show `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolTip` by adding listener on `SWT.Arm` event on `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 0):

> public void setToolTipText (String toolTip)

method was added to `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem`, since the version 3.104.